# How can I check if a key has already been assigned to a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function which is passed a txt file as an argument. The txt file contains 2 letters on each line and the function turns these 2 letters into a dictionary with the first letter being the key and the second letter being the value.
Here is the function:

```
def createdict(x):
    with open(x, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
        lines = [i.split(" ") for i in lines]
        encoding = {}
        for i in lines:
            encoding[i[0]] = i[1]
    return 0
```

How can I check if a key has already been assigned to the dictionary so that the key is not reassigned to a new value?

Comment: You can use `if key not in yourdictionary:` to do some work if key is not in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the key is present or not using the property of python and dictionary

```
def createdict(x):
    with open(x, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
        lines = [i.split(" ") for i in lines]
        encoding = {}
        for i in lines:
            if i[0] in encoding:
                # Key i[0] is present in the dictionary
                # Do your stuff here
            else:
                # Key is not present
                encoding[i[0]] = i[1]
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler note, you can just use the in function to check the keys in dictionary, as you use them with lists,

You can just use

```
if yourkey in dictionary:
    #conditionals
else:
    #conditionals
```

Hope this helps :)